# What does my textbook mean by Hypothesis here?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am reading through page 278 of the textbook "Calculus: Early Transcendentals" 8th Edition, by James Stewart. I am confused by his use of the word "hypothesis" here. I thought a hypothesis was essentially an educated guess?

[image]

What does the author mean by "hypothesis" here?

Comment: The assumptions of the theorem.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thank you, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Hypothesis here means the assumptions of the theorem, the 'if' part. For example, if the theorem goes, "If $f$ is a continuous function on a closed interval, then...", the hypothesis is the assumption of continuity and closed interval.

Comment: The theorem assumed certain things (continuity and closed interval). The author is referring to these, saying how the theorem does not hold anymore if one of these assumptions is omitted.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri So basically the author's saying the functions in figures 9 and 10 don't match to requirements of the absolute value theorem and therefore do not have both absolute minimum and maximum values?

Comment: The author wants to say that functions not satisfying the assumptions of the theorem _may_ not have absolute maximum/minimum, whilst the ones that do will _necessarily_ have these extrema.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri OH! I see, thank you! Sometimes the way math textbooks phrase things, confuse me.

Comment: Any theorem is of the form "If A then B".  The "hypothesis" is "A".  That has nothing to do with a guess, "educated" or not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you must have read the Extreme Value Theorem.  It has "assumption" and "results". The "assumptions" are called hypotheses:

> Extreme Value Theorem:
>
> Hypothesis: Let $f$ be a continuous, real-valued function to the closed interval $[a,b]$
>
> Conclusion: Then $f$ attains extreme values on that interval

Comment: I guess an "extreme value" is a value greater or less than all other values in that interval?

Comment: Yes exactly.  More rigorously, extreme values would be defined like this for Extreme Value Theorem: there exists $c,d$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(c)\leq f(x) \leq f(d)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$